# Apollo server RESTDataSource - accept self signed certificates

Tags: javascript, apollo-server, self-signed-certificate

When implementing a [RESTDataSource](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-server/tree/master/packages/apollo-datasource-rest) class for an Apollo server instance, how can I make it accept self signed certificates from my target REST API for development purposes?

I have `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED`set to `0` within my project, but this at least seems to have no impact.

Is there a rejectUnauthorised configuration option I can somehow set perhaps?

Answer (score 1):

It proved to be a problem with my webpack configuration in the end, and a misunderstanding of how the `webpack.DefinePlugin` plugin works. With this corrected, setting `process.env.NODE_TLS_REJECT_UNAUTHORIZED` to `"0"` did in fact have the desired effect.